# Can a group of instances be created with one already created instance?

Tags: wordpress, cloud, instances

I have in google cloud one instance created and in production. The instance is for one online store made with wordpress/woocommerce. I'm thinking in create a CDN and use Load Balancer. My question is, can I use that instance and create clones of that instance for load balancing? How can I do this? What do you suggest me to do? Create a new manage group of instances?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a template of your instance and configure an managed instances group. It will give you the autscalling capability you are looking for.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your replay. I have a instance in Production, how can I create a template of that instance? or it is better to create a template instance from the beginning and them configure instances group?

Comment: You should find everything documentation on the Google Cloud website : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/create-delete-deprecate-private-images